# I want to use OpenSUSE repositories in SLES 15 SP2

Tags: sles, zypper

I have no remote access to my RMT zypper repositories from a machine installed in another location, but I want to add zypper repositories to install software using zypper.

Is there an OpenSUSE zypper repository I can use to install software in SLES 15 SP2?

Specifically, I want to install common open source software developer tools (git, make).

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/36638390/823282

Comment: yes, you can just add the default repositories https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories -- but I'm not sure if the duplicate question answers my question generically.